# Ajax callback function behaving randomly. What have i done wrong?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have following ajax function that behaves randomly. Sometimes alert `success finally` is displayed. On other occasions, second alert that is
`Failure: my status is 500` is displayed.

`promptId` is passed on from the calling function. I have checked the `prompturl` and `promptId`. A valid value
of `promptId` is displayed on both occasions (success and failure). Also the audio file that I am trying to play is played in both cases (success and failure).
I can not figure out the cause for this random behavior of alerts being displayed.

If `500 error` is coming then it means , resource is not found, but my app is able to access the resource(that is playing the audio file).

```
function ajax_playPrompt(promptId) {
alert(promptId)


 var playPromptUrl = soapUrl + "?action=playPrompt&promptId=" + escape(promptId) +     "&parentSessionId=" + parentSessionId;
alert(playPromptUrl);
playPrompt_http_request = getNewHttpRequest('text/plain');
playPrompt_http_request.onreadystatechange = callback_ajax_playPrompt;  
playPrompt_http_request.open("GET", playPromptUrl, true);   
playPrompt_http_request.send(null);
 }

function callback_ajax_playPrompt() {
    if (playPrompt_http_request.readyState != 4) {
        alert("Returning bcause not 4");        
        return;
    }

    if (playPrompt_http_request.status == 200) {
        alert("Success finally");        
    } 
    else {        
        alert("Failure:My status is "+playPrompt_http_request.status );   // this gives status as 500     
    }
}
```

Also to support different browser I am using:

```
// to provide support for different browsers.
function getNewHttpRequest(contentType) {
    var myRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        myRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (myRequest.overrideMimeType) {
        myRequest.overrideMimeType(contentType);
    }
    return myRequest;
}
```

Additional Info: I have multiple audio files. When I play an audio file the first time, I get the failure alert first time(even though audio is played), but during if I play it again, second time, success alert is displayed.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't use jQuery's ajax function? It would reduce your lines of code significantly

Comment: try removing alert when (readyState!=4) use console.log instead if you need it.

Comment: @LNT I tried without the alert too but it still shows the random behavior. I just put the alert later on to verify that function is hitting that point or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
function ajax_playPrompt(promptId) {
       alert(promptId)
        var playPromptUrl = soapUrl + "?action=playPrompt&promptId=" + 
          escape(promptId) +     "&parentSessionId=" + parentSessionId;
       alert(playPromptUrl);
       var playPrompt_http_request = getNewHttpRequest('text/plain');
       playPrompt_http_request.onreadystatechange = function {
               if (playPrompt_http_request.readyState != 4) {
                      alert("Returning bcause not 4");        
                      return;
                  }

                     if (playPrompt_http_request.status == 200) {
                     alert("Success finally");        
              } else {        
                      alert("Failure:My status is "+playPrompt_http_request.status );
             }
       };  
       playPrompt_http_request.open("GET", playPromptUrl, true);   
       playPrompt_http_request.send(null);
 }
```

Comment: Yes,because declaring it globally all the following events are making changes to your global var, which will always giv in unexpected results

Comment: Comment deleted by mistake: Question was - the only change that you have done is declaring "playPrompt_http_request" locally? I am sorry i missed adding the info that i decalred it globally.

Comment: i tried declaring a local variable, but still the error persists

Comment: i tried declaring "playPrompt_http_request" locally, but the error persists.

Comment: can create jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: Though i am newbie to jsfiddle, lemme give it a shot.

Comment: I tried to creat a jsfiddle. Dont know whether this is correct way or not. http://jsfiddle.net/p2cNk/

Comment: can u change to 'this' in  your function 'callback_ajax_playPrompt'   or check this out http://jsfiddle.net/p2cNk/2/

Comment: I apologise LNT for missing out on this information again, but i have already tried with 'this'. Doesn't work

Comment: have you updated jsfiddle so that i can see latest code what your writing exactly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53828/discussion-between-lnt-and-akshay)